# pointer and then object after new operator in C++

Tags: c++, new-operator

I got this snippet of code and if you see in the return statement
of NewNode after new in bracket i have buff.
What does this buff in bracket is doing in new statement.

```
 struct Node
    { int key; }

    Node* NewNode(int key)
    {char *buff = allocate();
    ...
    return new (buff) Node(key)}
```

Comment: This is a special case of construction. Normally, the `new` is responsible to allocate memory _and_ call the constructor according to object type (in your case `NewNode`). In your case, the allocation is done prior. To consider this, [_placement `new`_](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new#Placement_new) is used which does only call of constructor using the given address `buff`.

Comment: @user007 Based on the reasonable answer, this is a duplicate. Concerning the title and text, the question asks for it without using the term - it's hard to search for "placement new" if you don't know that/what it is. ;-)

Comment: I rest my case i never knew about the term  "placement new" in C++ thanks